# Hyperlink in . properties file

Tags: java, html, jsp, properties

how to add a hyperlink in .properties file for Java/Spring web application.

In my message.properties file , i have `key1= Please <a href="www.google.com">Click me</a>`

This is displaying as it is on the web page along with the html tags.
Please suggest .

Comment: The code in your question worked for me on a struts 2 app. I just needed to refresh the server. You might have been calling the properties file incorrectly. But that is how you use a link within the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

USing `<c:out>` will escape your characters as you need.
Example:

```
<c:out value="${key1}"/>
```

Examples here: [c:out](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm)